# jQuery - Disable prototype script

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to use jQuery to prevent something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js"></script>
```

from executing on a page? I added disabled="disabled" and even ran a .remove() on it, but the protoype script is still functioning as if I didn't remove it. 
Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Any reason why you cannot disable its inclusion on the server side?

Comment: @NielsB. A third party site uses prototype and I'm trying to disable it altogether with jquery from firebug

Comment: @hjpotter92 I saw that question and answers, but it's definitely not a duplicate.

Comment: A third party site? How does (content from) this third party site make it's way into your site? Can you provide more details?

Comment: @Niels B. If you visit a site say SO that has prototype running on it, and you want to temporarily stop it to run some jquery functions without prototype interfering (and without using no conflict as it seems not to be working in this scenario), I was wondering if this can be done with jQuery

Comment: No, you can't do that with jQuery. You will need a tool to either modify the incoming http response and strip the script tag for Prototype before hitting the browser or you will need a tool that will block the http request for Prototype and return a 404.

Either way, none of these have anything to do with preventing Prototype from loading using jQuery, but rather with intercepting the network traffic.

Comment: @NielsB. if you put it as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks for the information Niels

Comment: It is not possible do stop jQuery from firebug. you will have to stop it coming from server.you need a tool to modify HTTP request as all data from server to us is served by HHTP request.If you find the solution let us also know thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do using just jQuery.

You will need a tool to either modify the incoming http response and strip the script tag for Prototype before hitting the browser or you will need a tool that will block the http request for Prototype and return a 404. Either way, none of these have anything to do with preventing Prototype from loading using jQuery, but rather with intercepting the network traffic.